# How do I style my XPages InputTextarea so it shows full height dependent on content? (in both edit and read mode)

Tags: xpages

I've got a simple `inputTextarea` contained in a `xp:table`.  I want to display it all opened up, and not have a scroller on the right. `style="width:100%; height:auto"` doesn't seem to do anything.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best route here is to use the Dojo Textarea control, `xe:djTextarea` - it does just what you're describing.

Comment: That's perfect Jesse.  I never know what other properties can be set and which ones do what, with these Dojo controls.   Are there any good references around?

Comment: Maybe you also need a dojo <xe:djBorderContainer ...> control, instead of the table.

Comment: The XPage-ized controls do a pretty good job of including explicit properties on the "Properties" tab. Beyond that, you can use the Dojo docs; I think recent releases use 1.9. https://dojotoolkit.org/api/